# Include an additional column with aggregate()

Tags: r, aggregate, plyr, minimum

I have written some code to look at data frame and create a new data frame by the minimum in one column, splitting by a factor. However, I can't figure out how to include another column in the result (without using it as a factor).

For example, the following code creates a data frame with the columns "State", "Institution", "Rating1", "Rating2", and "Junkdata". It then finds the minimum of Rating 1 for each state listed, and creates a data frame with each minimum for each state. But say I want to include the "Institution" column. How do I do that?
I've messed around with some plyr solutions, too, but no dice.

Here are the codes I used without specifying the "Institution" column, suffice to say I've tried putting it in there every place I can think of without success.

```
##create the data frame
State <- c("AZ","AZ","AZ","CA","CA","CA","CA","CA","NY","NY","NY","NY","SD","SD")
Institution <- c("Institution 1","Institution 2","Institution 3","Institution 4","Institution 5","Institution 6","Institution 7","Institution 8","Institution 9","Institution 10","Institution 11","Institution 12","Institution 13","Institution 14")
Rating1 <- c(3.4, 5.6,2.2,6.3,8.3,2.1,3.3,9.7,7.7,5.4,9.9,3.2,6.1,5.2)
Rating2 <- c(8.4,3.4,6.5,2.5,7.5,4.2,5.6,8.3,4.9,3.3,1.1,8,7.7,3.3)
Junkdata <- c("junk","more junk","superfluous","junk","more junk","superfluous","junk","more junk","superfluous","junk","more junk","superfluous","junk","more junk")
data.df <- data.frame(State, Institution, Rating1, Rating2, Junkdata)

## Use aggregate to find the minimum of Rating 1 for each State
new.df <- aggregate(data.df$Rating1 ~ State, data.df, min)
```

Using plyr:

```
library(plyr)
new.df.2 <- ddply(new.df, .(State), summarise, min=min(data.df$Rating1))
```

Comment: I think you're using the wrong tool(s), you are describing subsetting data `data.df[!!ave(data.df$Rating1, data.df$State, FUN = function(x) x == min(x)), 1:3]`, `aggregate` and `summarise` perform calculations on subsets of data. It's a bit confusing that the results are the same because the `min` is unchanged whether you do filtering or aggregation/summarization

Comment: That works too! I dont really understand what the double exclamation point is doing though. With respect to using mean, sum, etc, those would not make sense in the context of what I am trying to do.

Comment: that `ave` I used returns `c(0, 1, 0)` etc and `!!c(0, 1, 0)` just turns it into logicals. or equivalently `as.logical(c(0, 1, 0))` but the other way is faster. I got it from @akrun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to do via dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

resultDF <- data.df %>%
  group_by(State) %>%
  filter(Rating1 == min(Rating1))
```

The trick is to group by state. Then when you apply the filter operation you're only looking within each state and you select the row where the Rating1 is the minimum of all the Rating1 values within that state.

**In response to question in comment**
If you want to include just State, Institution and Rating1, you can do the following Chain:

```
resultDF <- data.df %>%
  group_by(State) %>%
  filter(Rating1 == min(Rating1)) %>%
  select(State, Institution, Rating1)
```

Comment: Ok, that's an improvement, but is there a way to include just the "Institution" but not the "Junkdata" column ( suppose I could just include another line to remove the columns I don't want, but that seems awkward).

Comment: @JamesHanks: Please see my revision. It shows you how to select specific columns. Also, if this solves your questions, please click the "check mark" to mark this answer as solved (plus that's a way to assign points and give credit).

Comment: Yes, that did it! Thank you!